# How should I clean user input if I am not writing to a databse?

Tags: php, html, security, user-input

I have a simple web page with a textarea that when multiple lines of tab delineated text is input, a php script processes the text and outputs the resulting string as a text file for the user to download.

The page itself is nothing more than a textarea and a submit button that posts to itself.  If post data is received, it basically creates an array of the lines of text in the textbox (using `explode("\n",$text)`, then loops through each line and creates an array of each section of text in the line (using `explode("\t",$text)`.  Finally, it takes each element in the array and constructs a string with it.  The only other php function used in the script is the `date` function and the `strtotime` function along with a couple of `foreach` statements.

When the string is complete, the string is sent to the browser as a text file using a few `header()` functions (`Content-Disposition: attachment;` , `Content-Type:` , etc). So, assuming `$str` is the string, this is how it is sent to the browser:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"')
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($str));
echo $str;
exit();
```

For example, suppose the text supplied is this (pretend the spaces between text are tabs)

```
John    Smith    Freshman
Jane    Doe      Sophomore
```

Then the script creates a string as follows:

```
Student:\nfirstname:John\nlastname:Smith\nYear:Freshman\nEndStudent\nStudent:\nfirstname:Jane\nlastname:Doe\nYear:Sophomore\nEndStudent\n
```

And that script is sent to the browser as a `text/plain` file.

The script works fine, the output file is correct.  My question is what kind of security holes am I leaving myself open and is it possible to close them ( and how to close them ).  I would like the page to be public.

Comment: Depend's how you're writing/creating the file via php - mind sharing that bit of code?

Comment: @Darren
Actually, there is no file created on the server.  The string that is processed is simply echoed after the headers are created.  I edited my post above to show the code that does this.

Comment: `header('Connection: close')` *after* the body output is nonsense/has no effect/won't be sent anyway. Omit it. You can also omit `exit`; I'd assume your script would exit by itself anyway after the last line...

Comment: @deceze I edited the post to reflect the unnecessary `'Connection: close'` command.  However, I need the `exit()` because there is HTML after the script which gets shown if there is no POST data.  However, I don't think either of those affects the script's security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're never *interpreting* the text and *execute* any code in response to *instructions* found within the text, there's absolutely no security concern here.

The only thing you'd need to be careful about is the use of *special characters*: your output uses specific characters with a certain meaning, namely `\n`. If your input contained a `\n`, and you're passing that trough to the output as is, would your output's meaning change? Perhaps you need to *escape* or *remove* any `\n` found in the input.